# Routing domain root to one app, a sub-uri to another app in Apache

Tags: apache, routes, virtual-hosts

I'm trying to run two apps on one domain with Apache, with the main app  at the domain 'root' `www.sitename.com`, and the sub-app at `www.sitename.com/blog`.

Currently I'm trying to achieve it this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.sitename.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sitename/main/public/
    Alias /blog /var/www/sitename/blog/
</VirtualHost>
```

Currently this works for the root of the blog app. Going to `www.sitename.com/blog` loads up the blog root, and going to `www.sitename.com` gets the main app. Static files are retrieved successfully.

However, any URLs beyond `/blog`, e.g. `/blog/postname` get handled by the main app and get a 404.

I also tried using an `AliasMatch` to specifically send `/blog` requests to the blog app's `index.php`. This worked in terms of avoiding 404s on deeper urls, but broke requests to the blog app's static files.

What I'd like is if this was possible:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.sitename.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sitename/public/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.sitename.com/blog
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sitename/blog/
</VirtualHost>
```

I.e., all requests to `/blog` simply get routed to the `/blog/` directory and handled from there. But you can't do it that way with virtual hosts.

How should this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I would probably just redirect /blog to blog.sitename.com and host your blog there.  That takes care of relative vs. absolute links and solves the problem of having two apps on a single root.  They can still be on the same server, of course, just in different VirtualHosts.

If you can't, or don't want to, an Alias should work.  I would make sure the slashes match, though.  So `Alias /blog/ /var/www/sitename/blog/` or `Alias /blog /var/www/sitename/blog`

See also [the Apache documentation on Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias).

Comment: I did try just using a subdomain, and it was easier to achieve. However, the two apps also share static files from `static.sitename.com`, and I'd rather avoid hardcoding that URL into the apps - nicer if they can behave the same on local dev and on production.

Comment: I tried using an alias `/blog /var/www/sitename/blog` and `/blog/ /var/www/sitename/blog/`. Both behave the same as described in the question.

Comment: @glasstree I'm not sure why having static files from `static.sitename.com` would be a problem in either solution, and how it would affect dev/production.

Comment: Sorry, should've been clearer. So that the site can easily refer to static from files from `static.` whatever domain it's on.

Comment: @glasstree I'm still not sure how that affects anything.  If you want to link to another domain/site for static files, you'll have to put that somewhere, like in a config file.  Why can't you do that for both?  How would it be different if it was a single site with two apps vs. two sites (with a single app each)?